# What is causing discoloration around door latch

Tags: detailing

What is causing dull film under left side  of door latch and what is best way to get rid of it? Also had same thing around tailgate and other door latch.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely wear on the paint due to opening the door. You have something in your hand and it hangs down. You unlatch the door via the handle and whatever is in your hand bangs against the car paint onto the car door. If you pay attention to what you do, you'll discover you and your passengers do this more often than you ever figured you would. If you look at the ring around the door handle, you can see the wear pattern on it as well.

The only way to fix this on the paint is to buff out the clear coat with buffing compound. If you are unfamiliar with how to accomplish this, I'd highly suggest you take it to a professional.